# How to Float-Left and Flot-Right in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am a learner of CSS and HTML and I have a task to create file with HTML and CSS using Float-Left and Float-Right.

**Here is an image which i want to create**

[image]

I have Done everything using HTML and CSS but i failed to display images as shows above

**Here is Output of my Code**

[image]

**And Here is My CSS CODE**

```
body{
    background-color:#666;

    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}

    h1{
        color:#FFF;
    }
#color{
    border:dotted 2px #F90;
    background-color:black;
    width:670px;
    margin:0 auto;
    alignment-adjust:central; 

}

.float-left{ 
    display:block;
    background-color:white;
    margin:20px 50px 20px px;
    padding:20px;
    float:none;
}   
.white{ 
background-color:white;
    border:solid 1px red;
    margin:15px 40px 15px 40px;
    padding:2px;
    font-style:italic;
}
.purple{
    background-color:white; 
    border:solid 1px red;
    margin:15px 40px 15px 40px;
    padding:2px;
    font-style:italic;

}
```

**AND Here is HTML Code**

```
<body>

    <!--<div class="background">-->
    <div id="color">
    <div id="float-left">
    <h1>Float Left</h1>
    <div class="white">

        <div class="float-left"><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EQ_mYstNGwg/maxresdefault.jpg" width="93" height="77" alt="img" />
        </div> 
        <p> thiojds jeifwk mskodiw dmkmx wmsoak.dwsqksmi wnsmakxn,dwenddjewjn,wksmdwdwm,dwkkmsakwi,iwdjwkiw.dwjidjwwij
        .wijdksxkmddos.
        sdsjkjie nennnwj snjdnwinda wqndjf sdnjiajanx jssnxjnxsnxs asnjxsnxssjxnss asdnjxnn nsjndcd dkmcdkdi ewin wjdke jndiisn dweidns iwqjss wiji pqw9sm.sdjdwqi eewiow oqskawiqo djaskd,ssssssssssssssswi isssssssseiw kdkddjmsqo ejfnjf fndjfow wkm.dmewomdiwq oqwsk widsie oqwsqkiwj ksiw assjjdi wqijdi wiqojid wddid wkdi qoiasjkdj asjidjs iojdskdkso odjosij</p>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
    <h1> Float Right</h1>
    <div class="purple">
        <div class=""><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EQ_mYstNGwg/maxresdefault.jpg" width="88" height="76" alt="img" />
       </div> 
            <p> thiojds jeifwk mskodiw dmkmx wmsoak.dwsqksmi wnsmakxn,dwenddjewjn,wksmdwdwm,dwkkmsakwi,iwdjwkiw.dwjidjwwij
            .wijdksxkmddos
            .sdsjkjie nennnwj snjdnwinda wqndjf sdnjiajanx jssnxjnxsnxs asnjxsnxssjxnss asdnjxnn nsjndcd dkmcdkdi ewin wjdke jndiisn dweidns iwqjss wiji pqw9sm.sdjdwqi eewiow oqskawiqo djaskd,ssssssssssssssswi isssssssseiw kdkddjmsqo ejfnjf fndjfow wkm.dmewomdiwq oqwsk widsie oqwsqkiwj ksiw assjjdi wqijdi wiqojid wddid wkdi qoiasjkdj asjidjs iojdskdkso odjosij</p>
    </div>
            </div>
            </div>


</body>
```

**AND Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywozhrco/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```css
.post-container {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    border: 5px solid #333;
    overflow: auto
}
.post-thumb {
    float: left
}
.post-thumb img {
    display: block
}
.post-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">                
    <div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff" /></div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
        <p>post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post descdesc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post descdesc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post descdesc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post descdesc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc </p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much

Comment: Welcome Sunny !! :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .float-left{ 
>     display:block;
>     background-color:white;
>     margin:20px 50px 20px px;
>     padding:20px;
>     float:none;
> }
> ```

To float left you have to give `float` the value `left` and not `none`.

To float right, you need to write some rules for your `float-right` class.

Comment: Thank You For Helping Me. Can you please edit My Fiddle For ME?

Answer (score 0):

You put the css property `float: left` on the image that you want to put on left and the property `float: right` on the image you want to put on the right.

And couple of suggestions, buddy. No need to place your `<img>` inside a `<div>` and with this, you can put the `float` properties *on the img element itself*, not on it's parent div (as it might ruin the layout).